# Integration testing rails-api model using rspec and fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm pretty new to Rails and I've finished (I think) my rails API, and now I'm up to test it.
Say I have this model:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parents

  validates :id, presence: true 
  validates :type, presence: true
  validates :parent_id, presence: true

  before_create :update_child_if_exists

  private 
  def update_child_if_exists
    conditions = {type: self.type, parent_id: self.parent_id}

    if existing_measure = Child.find_by(conditions) # or Child.where(conditions).last
      new_values = (existing_child.values || []) + [self.values]
      existing_measure.update_attribute(:values, new_values)
    end
  end
end
```

This is meant to update a field in the child table if the record by `type` and `parent_id` already exists, else it would be created. How can I write a test for this using `RSpec`?
Any help would be much appreciated, I'm pretty lost here.

If any additional information is needed, please ask me and I will provide it.

Comment: This involves a lot of coding(in fact, you should have written specs during implementation according to requirements of this method), so this question appears to be too broad. You should show what have you tried and what difficulties you faced.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try to work on something and get back with my results. I'm really new to Rails and testing an API with no interface gets confusing for me. Let's see what I can come up with (I was only able to test basic controller functionalities for now)